# Virtualbox guest ubuntu mate 20.04 adjusts screen but same guest with plasma kde can not

Tags: virtualbox, kde, screen

Running virtualbox 6.1.6 on Kubuntu 20.04 I have a guest with Ubuntu Mate 20.04 and virtualbox extensions and it will adjust to my newly dragged screen dimensions.  I also installed kubuntu-desktop on same guest.  When I log in to the kubuntu-desktop on same guest, it no longer adjusts to my newly dragged out screen dimension.

Additionally, I have a guest with Kubuntu 20.04 with vbox guest additions installed, but it also won't resize, which of course is why I installed Ubuntu; and since that does resize, I figured I'd try to pop KDE on there.  Something is different, I'm thinking the video driver may have changed?  What do ya think?